# Make NSTextField accept return & enter without ending editing

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I'm currently coding a text editor in swift and I'm having trouble with inserting a new line ("\n") when pressing enter/return.

**By now, when pressing enter, the textField inserts a new line but ends editing with no reason.**

Here is my function which will only be called when enter is pressed.

```
@IBAction func textFieldAction(_ sender: NSTextField) {
    self.textField?.stringValue.append("\n")
    self.textField?.selectAll(nil)
}
```

If there is more of my code needed the whole file can be found here:
https://github.com/notalent/manuscript-mac/blob/master/Manuscript/Document.swift

Comment: Why aren't you using a `TextView` instead?

Comment: Because as far as I know you can't set an (attributed) placeholder for NSTextView

Comment: Yes, you can and it's easier than you might think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428594/set-the-placeholder-string-for-nstextview/43028577#43028577 ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the correct answer is "don't use `NSTextField`; use [NSTextView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextview)". `NSTextField` wasn't designed to do what you're trying to do. The [Cocoa Text Architecture Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/Introduction/Introduction.html) has a bunch of information on both `NSTextField` and `NSTextView`. See also [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398175/nstextfield-or-nstextview#2398980).

But, if you insist on using `NSTextField`, you can implement the delegate method [`control:textView:doCommandBySelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscontroltexteditingdelegate/1428898-control?language=objc) to provide special handling of return/enter keys (among other things) in an `NSTextField`. See [Apple's Technical Q&A QA1454, "How to make NSTextField accept tab, return and enter keys"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1454/_index.html).

Seriously, though... just use `NSTextView`. :)